# How to get size of folder without taking ownership?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ntfs

Is it possible to see how much space a folder I don't have permission to access (like `Windows\TEMP` or the Windows Store App repository) uses without taking ownership of it?

Comment: you could open a command line window as the owner of the folder and then do a dir c:\temp

Comment: Locally? Over the network? Over the internet? What do you mean by TAKING ownership? Copying the folder to your computer? Having permission to view it?

Comment: @Wutnaut Locally, and yes it's owned by some  system account so I don't have permission to view it.

Comment: @DrNoone This gives a permission denied error.

Comment: If it's the only subfolder in that folder that you don't have permission to, you could use process of elimination to find it's size.

Comment: @Wutnaut That won't work. If you look at the size of C:\foo it will show the size of all readable items in the folder. But if you can't read C:\foo\bar then it won't show in the total. If you take ownership of C:\foo\bar or get read access, then it's size will show up in the size of C:\foo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would at least need read access to the folder, otherwise you won't be able to read the size.